# php if something equals x, y or z

Tags: php, if-statement

I am writing out some php logic, and I'm trying to simplify something.

Is it possible to write something like the following:

```
<?php if( (get_theme_mod('header_image_location')=='x', 'y' or 'z' ) {?> 
    //Do something 
<?php } ?>
```

I must I do it like this:

```
<?php if( (get_theme_mod('header_image_location')=='x') ||  (get_theme_mod('header_image_location')=='y') || (get_theme_mod('header_image_location')=='z') ) {?> 
    //Do something 
<?php } ?>
```

Just want to know if I can simplify the bottom example. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an array of values, then use `in_array`.

```
<?php if( in_array(get_theme_mod('header_image_location'), array('x', 'y', 'z'))){?> 
    //Do something 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `in_array()`

```
if (in_array(get_theme_mod('header_image_location'), array('x','y','z'))) {

}
```

Comment: We both just posted the same answer at the same time!